# git push --force has no effect

Tags: git, push, git-filter-branch

I've done a filter-branch on my local repository and now I'm trying to push the changes to the remote repo with

```
git push origin --all --force
```

The response I get is

```
Everything up-to-date
```

which is unexpected. And indeed, if I then do

```
git pull
```

I see that the local branches are force-updated
What might be the cause of that?

Comment: I myself am confused by how `git push` works. However, did you try pushing with explicit arguments? e.g. `git push --force GitHub master mybranch`

Comment: Are you on your master branch? Or a different branch that may not have been pushed to the remote yet?

Comment: I'm on dev and the branch has been pushed to the remote